# Perl/Tk: Access Button text before MainLoop

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

Consider following example:

```
use strict;
use Tk;

my $w = tkinit;
$w->withdraw;

my $b = $w->Button(
    -text => "Test", 
    -command => \&test,
    )->pack();

$w->Popup;

print "Text: " . $b->cget(-text) . "\n";

MainLoop;

sub test
{
    print "Text: " . $b->cget(-text) . "\n";
}
```

As soon as program starts I see `Text:` in the output instead of `Text: Test`. If I press the button, the output is correct. How do I access button property `-text` before invoking `MainLoop`?

Perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
Tk version: 804.031

Comment: I can't say where the problem is but, your code worked for me using Strawberry Perl 5.12.3 and Tk-804.032-1390844252 on Win 7 64.  Had Perl already installed and used "cpanp i Tk" to install Tk.

Comment: Works for me, too. Tk 804.031, Perl 5.16.0, Linux.

Comment: Please print to STDERR instead of STDOUT to avoid output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a $b->update; right before $w->Popup;.

Note: here, on Win 8.1 x64 with Perl 5.16.3 and Tk 801.031 it works fine even without the update.